# Django ajax passing variable to the views

Tags: django, django-views, django-ajax-selects

I'm new with Django + Ajax. My Problem is I can't get the value from my ajax `POST` request. I'm using the `jquery post`.

My task is to sort the draggable list item. The drag and drop is not the problem. Getting the values from `POST` request is the problem. It returns `MultiValueDictKeyError`

`"Key 'ages' not found in <QueryDict: {u'action': [u'updateRecords'], u'ages[]': [u'80', u'81', u'79', u'82', u'83', u'84', u'85', u'86']}>"`

here is my ajax:

```
$(function() { 
    var url = ""; /* won't place it*/
    $("ul#ages").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecords';
            $.post(url, order, function(theResponse){
                alert('success');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

here is the views:

```
if request.is_ajax():
        if request.POST['action'] == "updateRecords":
            update_record_array = request.POST['ages']

            order_counter = 1;

            for record_id in update_record_array:
                Age.objects.filter(id=record_id).update(order_id=order_counter)
                order_counter += 1
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows what is wrong - you're looking up a key `ages`, but you're sending something called `ages[]` with some extra square brackets.

If you've put those brackets in the field name, you don't need them - that's a PHP-ism. (It might not be your fault: jQuery has been known to do add them itself.) In any case, you'll want to use `request.POST.getlist(fieldname)` to get the list of multiple values associated with that key.